# KMeans clustering for the following mixed variable data

Tags: k-means, categorical-data

Can somebody help me with this problem?

I'm learning KMeans clustering concepts. I know how to cluster if the variables are continuous. But this data set contains categorical/discrete variables like gender and zip code.

```
Sno Age Gender Zip  Salary
1   26  0   9822    100
2   38  1   9822    700
3   19  1   9822    100
4   64  0   9810    2500    
5   53  1   9810    1200
6   75  1   9810    1800
7   19  0   9822    75
8   36  1   9822    350
9   42  1   9875    1800
10  41  0   9875    750
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-Means works only with numerical data.

K-means fails for categorical data because taking the mean of categorical data doesn't make sense at all. Neither does distance. Some people run the data on K-means by using one hot encoding. But this too doesn't give the right clusters.

To solve this kind of problem you can look at another variation of K-Means called the K-Prototype algorithm which works well for a mix of Categorical and Numerical data.

Check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kmodes/

This link contains the paper and the python package for using this algorithm. It's easy to understand as well.